# ImageMagick works in command line but when exec() in php it returns 5 with "incompatible library version"

Tags: php, imagemagick, macports

I'm having a bizarre problem with php 5.3.6 and ImageMagick (command line) using MAMP (and Macports too..I tried both) on OS X.

When I run the identify command from the CLI, it works fine. But when I run the exact same command using `exec()`, it returns a value code of `5` and in the apache error logs I have:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
>   Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/identify   Reason: Incompatible
>   library version: identify requires version 14.0.0 or later, but
>   libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0

E.g. 
The cli command is:
`/opt/local/bin/identify /Users/leonardteo/Documents/1.jpg`

This works just fine when executed from the command line.  When executed from PHP:

`exec("/opt/local/bin/identify /Users/leonardteo/Documents/1.jpg", $output, $return);`

`$return` is `5`

`$output` is nothing

Checking the apache logs gives the above issue with libfreetype.

I installed ImageMagick using Macports. I've also tried a manual build from source and running identify from `/usr/local/bin/identify` and I get the same result. I have also tried running PHP from Macports instead of MAMP and I get the same result.

Could someone please help shed light on this?

Comment: PHP is executing a different copy of that library, somehow.  Check your paths, make sure you don't have conflicting versions.

Comment: CLI php usually has a seperate .ini file from SAPI php, so the two .ini's can potentially be loading different versions of the library.

Comment: @Marc B: This isn't a problem between running php on cli and php through Apache. It's between an actual cli command on the bash shell and executing the exact same command through PHP.

Comment: Hmm. d'oh... right. Was imagick statically compiled into PHP? Could that it's got v14 internally, but you've installed v13 for the rest of the system.

Comment: No no I'm not trying to run IM compiled into PHP. I'm trying to execute it as a command line tool from within PHP using exec(). I installed two versions of IM: one is using Macports (which gives me the libfreetype error but only in PHP) and another one from source in /usr/local/bin (which also throws another error but again, only in PHP).

Comment: Oh my gosh. This is the answer:

Edit this file:

> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars

Comment out the following lines:

> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Restart MAMP/Apache.

And it works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit this file:

> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars

Comment out the following lines:

> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
>
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Nice, the other way would be to simply switch the server instance to XAMPP that works out of the box http://tekkie.flashbit.net/developer-tools/workaround-for-imagemagick-convert-returning-5

Comment: Thx a lot!!! It was trying for a couple of hours to find out the reason why it did not work. Fortunately StackOverflow and You, dear sir, saved my ass again ;)

Comment: On XAMPP, the path is `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/envvars`, and because I used homebrew, instead of commenting it out I swapped out `[...]/lib` with `/usr/local/lib`.