# Incompatible library version: imagick.so requires version 18.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 16.0.0 in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, mamp, imagick

I installed imagemagic and imagick successfully (using  http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php#94169 steps ) and also put extension=imagick.so.
but when i restart apache i am getting following error.

> Unable to load dynamic library
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so
>
> dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so,
>
> 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib Referenced
> from:
>
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so
>
> Reason: Incompatible library version: imagick.so requires version
> 18.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 16.0.0 in Unknown on line 0

I am using Mac OSX (10.8.5), php 5.5.3 under mamp

Any help appreciated on how to solve this! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit file

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars
```

Comment out the following lines:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812299/imagemagick-works-in-command-line-but-when-exec-in-php-it-returns-5-with-inco)